# Notification icon turns white in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to use a colorful image with transparent background as a notification icon.

This works fine in older Android versions but when I tested it on Marshmallow (Android 6.0), it turns white. I tried to find the solution on Google and tried them but with no success.

Here is my code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Activity_Notification.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("MSG", message);
if (notificationIntent != null) {
    int number = createRandomInteger();
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent;
    intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, number,
        notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(number, notification);
}
```

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Check this Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913952/android-notification-is-not-showing-colour-icon-in-marshmallow

Comment: Any suggestions as why have I got -ve. I will take care in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Android 5.0 behavior changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop/android-5.0-changes#NotificationsMaterialDesignStyle):

> The system ignores all non-alpha channels in action icons and in the main notification icon. You should assume that these icons will be alpha-only. The system draws notification icons in white and action icons in dark gray.

You can use [setColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor(int)) to change the background color visible on the notification, but the small icon will always only be alpha-only i.e., colored a single color by the system.

Answer (score 1):

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop), above Lollipop notification icon can only be white or transparent