# Statusbar Notification icon not shows correctly always shows white circle

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase for notification and sending notification using REST Api everything works fine but there is one problem notification icon of statusbar not showing properly always it shows white circle instead of my small icon set for notification.
I search a lot eveyone suggest that we can not use colorfull icon in notification but I saw everyone using colorfull icon.

See this image google play,Instagram, and so many application shows there logo

[image: see here]

I also attach image that i want to show in notification

[image: see here]

also I'm using transparent background but I'm not able to show correctly please help me and my English is very bad I'm sorry for that

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification Icon with the new Firebase Cloud Messaging system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325051/notification-icon-with-the-new-firebase-cloud-messaging-system)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Color Notification Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874742/android-color-notification-icon)

Comment: please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913952/android-notification-is-not-showing-colour-icon-in-marshmallow

Comment: @rafeek ,thunder ..... yes colorful icon is showing in large icon in my case even but main problem is small icon ..... I see all of this link and answer but not got the exact answer or detail about how other application able to show colorful icon in small icon of notificationcompat builder ....Btw thanks all of you

Comment: @AtulChaudhary what is the os version are you used?

Comment: @rafeek nougat and marshmallow

Comment: can u try fcm  meta-data in your manifest file    pls refer this

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Yes , I already used manifest default declaration but no luck

Comment: please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265595/android-status-bar-expects-icons-of-size-25x25dp-while-guidelines-recommend-32x3

Comment: please refer this one https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html#icon11

Answer (score 0):

Post android Lollipop release android has changed the guidelines for displaying notification icons in the Notification bar. The official documentation says "Update or remove assets that involve color. The system ignores all non-alpha channels in action icons and in the main notification icon. You should assume that these icons will be alpha-only. The system draws notification icons in white and action icons in dark gray.” Now what that means in lay man terms is "Convert all parts of the image that you don’t want to show to transparent pixels. All colors and non transparent pixels are displayed in white"

**Make sure your image file  will have in .png format with transparent background**

Comment: Yes i read all of this but my question is how other application shows colorful notification icon ....please visit this link and  guide me ..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6SSo.png
u can see playstore , insta and so many applications able to show colorful logo inside notification please watch this image first